# How many days Lord Krishna stayed at Sandipani's ashram?

Tags: krishna

I know that Lord Krishna stayed at Sandipani's ashram very few days and he completed his all education like 64 arts and 14 science. I don't know the exact figure of days what he stayed an ashram.

Comment: According to SB 10.45.36, Krishna had learnt 64 arts in **64 days.**